# Using a 220ohm resistor in a mains circuit?

Tags: resistors

I work in a charity shop where our display cabinet with a rotating glass shelf has stopped working.  The electrics are clearly visible, and the fault is that a 220 ohm resistor between the live lead and the motor has broken.  This is a 'normal' small resistor with no markings other than the resistance.

Can I replace the broken item with a standard 220 ohm resistor?

Comment: Define standard. 1/4W, 1/2W etc...  With additional information it would be irresponsible to go "yes just replace it"

Comment: It would be helpful to post a picture of the failed resistor.

Comment: Much like a blown fuse, it's quite likely that the failed resistor is a symptom of the true cause.  So you may find that replacing it only results in the new one failing as well.  I would try to check for other problems with the motor or wiring.

Comment: I should have made clear, but one lead from the resistor had broken - the stump is too short to consider soldering a new lead. So I do not think the problem was caused by another component failing.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Maybe that 220 ohm resistor was intended to work as a fuse?  If the motor stalls, the resistor will have a big fraction of mains voltage across it and turn into a LER.  (Light emitting resistor)

Comment: @Les you should edit that into the question.

Answer (score 8):

**Yes, But...**

"Normal" resistors do come in different sizes, voltage ratings, tolerances, and power dissipation ratings.  You need to replace the burnt out one with one which matches.

**Resistance**: Replace 220Ω with 220Ω. Easy

**Tolerance**: A resistor which is used in series with a motor is unlikely to have a fine tolerance. To be on the safe side, you should replace with the same or better.  E.g. 5% could be replaced with 5%, 2%, 1% etc.  Look at the last colour band to see what the tolerance is.

**Voltage rating**: There is no easy way to check the voltage rating of the resistor.  Unless you have a particular reason not to, just choose a voltage rating well above the mains voltage in your country.

**Power rating**: There's no easy way to check the power rating of the burnt out part either.  Most resistors of a given size have the same power rating though, so if you replace like with like, that should be fine.  Even better, you could go for a larger resistor with a higher power rating, that way it might not burn out again.

**Size**: Provided you can fit it in, there's probably no harm in picking a larger resistor.  The main change is the power rating.  Be careful about clearances though - the resistor may have lots of space around it to make sure it doesn't arc to another component or to the case.  Don't put a larger resistor in if you can't maintain that spacing.

Comment: There is no problem in fitting a larger resistor.  The problem is a broken lead, but easy to remove from the connector.  I'll check that the voltage rating is suitable.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: [It is *ohm*, not *Ohm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm).

Comment: 22 ohm or 220 ohm?

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure it is the resistor that's broken, you can. Remove the broken resistor and replace it with a new one. However, a resistor breaking seems odd to me. I would suggest measuring the actual resistance of the resistor with a multimeter. Do this when it is removed, otherwise you will measure other resistances of the circuit too. If it is broken, and you replace it, it could be it will break again soon, if the issue is caused by another component. Since resistors are really cheap, you can certainly replace it to see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: If the resistor is burned, measuring its resistance is fairly futile.

Comment: @Barleyman I believe he is suggesting to measure the resistance to ensure that it truly was broken.

Comment: No the resistor is not burnt; one of its wires had broken leaving a stump too short to consider a soldering repair.  Many thanks,

Comment: But what about the voltage rating for the resistor? Applying 12,000 volt across a (high-value) resistor will probably make it stop being a resistor in the normal sense.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  I have no way of knowing what the voltage rating of the broken 220Ohm resistor is; its only markings are the colour codes.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I replace the broken item with a standard 220 ohm resistor?

You should replace it with a resistor that has the same rating (resistance and power, voltage) as the damaged component.

The broken resistor can still be a symptom of more serious failures in the motor or something else. Even if from your description, it appears to be a simple mechanical problem.

<sub>This goes with the usual disclaimers: Tampering with mains-powered electric and electronic devices is always hazardous. Depending on where you are located, it may be illegal to operate devices that have been repaired by anyone else than a certified professional, and bring about nasty liability issues for you and the shop owner if the gadget starts a fire.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

First of all, confirm that the problem is in the resistor. If you are sure, then remove it from the circuit and check it out with a multimeter. If the multimeter shows a correct value of resistance, then problem not lies in resistor. If the resistance value is incorrect, then you need to replace the resistor.

A normal resistor in a small size is generally lesser in power rating. When the power rating value increases, the size of the resistor increases respectively. So, take that resistor with you when you are going to buy a new one after confirmation. Find a new one with a same resistance value and tolerance value.

Comment: ¡¡WARNING: FIRE IS HOT!!  Apart from the power rating (that's the correct term) related stuff, if even that, you're saying the obvious.  There are also two other answers that suggest verifying that it truly is the resistor which is at fault.

Comment: The resistor shows a measurement of 220ohm.   It is a mechanical problem due to a broken wire.  Thanks, Les

Answer (score -2):

First of all, check your resistance value using the multimeter without removing the resistor from the circuit. If it shows proper value, don't replace it. If it too high(infinity), please change it.

Comment: "without removing the resistor in the circuit" ??

Comment: dont you think that will give false reading rather than actual resistor value?

Comment: It's got to be replaced because its lead is broken.  I have checked its value and it is 220ohm.  Thanks,

Comment: @Mayank: In this case, from the description (no mention of anything in parallel with the resistor) you might be able to measure in-circuit and get an accurate result (but you're certainly right that in general you want to remove one end before measuring--and that *could* apply here as well).

Comment: No, there is nothing in parallel with the resistor; it connects the live mains lead to the motor directly.  Thank you, Les